# django form is invalid but has no errors

Tags: django, forms

my datefields in my django form render always as invalid, but no errors of the how and why are given. (I use both non_field_errors as field.errors )
My Form

```
class FilterJournalForm(forms.Form):
    end_initial = datetime.now(utc)
    from_initial = (end_initial - timedelta(days=30))
    from_date = forms.DateField(
        widget=forms.DateInput(format='%m-%d-%Y'),
        initial=from_initial,
        required=True,
    )
    end_date = forms.DateField(
        widget=forms.DateInput(format='%m-%d-%Y'),
        initial=end_initial,
        required=True,
    )
```

part of my view that has the form:

```
filter_form = FilterJournalForm(request.POST or None)
if request.POST:
    print request.POST
    if filter_form.is_valid():
        print "success"
```

My template part:

```
<form class="form-inline" action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ filter_form.from_date|add_css_class:"form-control input-sm" }}
    </div> until
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ filter_form.end_date|add_css_class:"form-control input-sm" }}
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" >Filter</button>
    {% if filter_form.errors %}
    <div id="form-error">
        <p>The operation could not be performed because one or more error(s) occurred.<br />{{ filter_form.non_field_errors }}</p>
    <ul>
    {% for field in form %}
        <li>{{ field.errors|striptags }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

Any idea what is going wrong here? (i also tried to change the initial input of my formfields to date.today() to see if datetime objects could be ruining it. But that as well is not the problem.
    {% endif %}

Comment: 2 things: `if filter_form.is_valid()` can be followed by an `else` where you can print `form.errors` to see what is the exact error. Also,  `{% if filter_form.errors %}` does not have a corresponding `{% endif %}` so, i am not sure how this template is not throwing an error - a copy/paste error may be ?

Comment: What is the *rest* of your view? Also, there can be errors not associated with a field: output `form.non_field_errors` in the template as well.

Comment: It seems that somehow the form doesnt load the request.POST
errors: <ul class="errorlist"><li>from_date<ul class="errorlist"><li>Enter a valid date.</li></ul></li><li>filters<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>end_date<ul class="errorlist"><li>Enter a valid date.</li></ul></li></ul>
request.POST: <QueryDict: {u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'l9B8s9KNAd6ezRyisvlqkmtqSo4G28vA'], u'from_date': [u'04-26-2015'], u'end_date': [u'05-26-2015'], u'filters': [u'']}>

Comment: Already know why errors didnt show. my forloop is on for field in form instead of for field in filter_form

Comment: When i input the date like   04/26/2015  it works, however, i wanted to do it with the "-" . .